# Glitches with report.c and report.java servlets on gwan 7.12.6

Tags: java, c, servlets, g-wan

This is a question sent to the gwan development folks.

Using the last gwan release 7.12.6 (with my Mint 17.3 system), both the report.c and report.java servlets don't display the System Uptime information.

However, using the exactly same report.c and report.java servlets (on the same Mint 17.3 system and odf course after a reboot) with the previous gwan release 4.12.25, the System Uptime information is well shown.

So, obviously this problem is with the last gwan 7.12.6 release internal code and not with these two identical (C and java) servlet codes.

Further, both of these two servlets display strange characters just above the "Traffic" section when reloading them (i.e. using the F5 keystroke on the browser).

Last, these two servlets now display under the "Listeners" section:

1 host(s): 0.0.0.0:80

root: 0.0.0.0

1 host(s): 0.0.0.0

root: 0.0.0.0

an not the 0.0.0.0:8081_PONG and its #0.0.0.0 sub folder.

You can check these strange behaviors on my gwan server at [lsd.dtdns.net](http://lsd.dtdns.net) using the two Server report servlets (last option of the Download page).

Any information would be truly appreciated with regard to these "glitches".

Best regards.

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

These "glitches" have indeed been reported - and immediately corrected. They are more cosmetic than relevant for development and don't prevent anyone from using G-WAN properly.

The new release is available to G-WAN registered users who enjoy, among other things, development releases.

May I suggest again to Paul that these kind of **non-technical questions** are rather asked on `serverfault.com` because `stackoverflow.com` is a Q&A platform for **developers**.